# Can I git svn rebase to a certain svn revision? (Similar to svn up -r ...)

Tags: git-svn, rebase

Short question: what is the git-svn equivalent of `svn up -r r1130` to update only to a numbered commit (with the svn number)?

I am using git-svn so I can both use git and manage (many) local branches of my team's svn repository.  I have a version of the software that I hack up to work with a particular hardware setup.  Since I last worked with it, the svn repo has moved forward past a stable, good point for this work.  I want to update the local branch to a numbered revision that represents the stable commit.  I could do this in svn with `svn up -r r1130`, but I prefer git.

I keep forgetting how I have done this in the past and finding myself searching SO and the help pages trying to find the best way.  Perhaps there is a differently worded Q&A that I'm missing?

It is easy enough to just check out the older revision on a clean tree, but when I am carrying commits on top of the tree, the "rewinding head to replay your work on top of it..." part that I usually love means that I will be going to a point in the tree before my changes were added!

For now, I am going to `git svn rebase` and then rebase interactively to back out the commits I don't want, but I am having trouble believing this is the best or even a good way of doing this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I prefer `rebase` because git-svn is going to have to rebase your changes anyway before a `dcommit`. Try this instead:

```
git checkout `git svn find-rev r1241`  # Go to the svn version of interest
git checkout -b master_r1241           # Create a new brach matching it
git checkout hwTesting                 # Merge previously created changes
git rebase master_r1241                # rebase on top of not quite up-to-date master branch
```

You could do this in one step also: (could always revert using reflog or `rebase --abort` if things go horribly wrong).

```
git checkout hwTesting                 # Checkout feature branch
git rebase `git svn find-rev r1241`    # rebase on top of not quite up-to-date master branch
```

Comment: I finally got a chance to try this out and the one step version of this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do it in one step.  You can, however, easily find the corresponding git commit id for a given svn revision number.  Try this:

```
git svn find-rev rN
```

where N is the revision number you want.  After that, use git checkout to checkout that specific point in the history.

Comment: This is a useful command that is generally helpful, but if I am in a branch that has new commits and I `git svn rebase` that branch, then it will replay my new commits on top of the svn commit in question.  Your command will check out the *unmodified* svn commit, i.e. without my changes committed on top.  Perhaps I could do this, then create a new branch at that point, and finally merge this new branch into my feature branch?

Comment: Good point... I think habitually I tend to git svn rebase on tracking branches only... that way my feature branches are untouched until they're ready to be integrated with the mainline.  I took your question to ask how to update and THEN move to a specific revision in the new commits.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this for reference, since the accepted answer mentions it.  Use the one-liner rebase option, though...

---

Here is what I am doing for now.  This time I am upgrading from r1130 (mentioned in the question) to r1241:

```
git checkout `git svn find-rev r1241`  # Go to the svn version of interest
git checkout -b hwTesting_r1241        # Create a new brach matching it
git merge hwTesting_r1130              # Merge previously created changes
```

This mostly gives me what I want, but it spawns another branch each time I update.  It seems like there should be some way to tell git to merge only the commits on master up to and including the one returned by `git svn find-rev r1241`.